# Dll в каждой вкладке

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать, у меня есть папка plugins И в ней будут храниться dll, как реализовать подобное: программа смотрит все dll ки в папке и создает для каждого вкладку в программе на PageControl создавалась вкладка с нужными элементами и желательно не трогала другие вкладки. Возможно ли такое? Хотя бы куда копать. Получить файлы и создать табы я смогу, но вот как быть с содержимым..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко:

DLL-ки должны реализовывать некий стандартный клиентский интерфейс (вернуть название плагина, информацию о версии, инициализацию и деинициализацию), а ваша программа должна реализовывать определенный "серверный" интерфейс (все вызовы, которые плагины могли бы дергать). При обходе плагинов в папке программа поочередно вызывает инициализацию плагина и передает ссылку на свой управляющий интерфейс. Дальше плагин через него что-то делает (добавляет кнопки на тулбары, отрисовывает окна и т.п.).

У Gunsmoker-а была [серия статей](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2011/12/delphi.html), которая все это по полочкам раскладывала.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень выручили меня!